# Aggregate Level Tracking in Salescloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, email-tracking

I configured the Marketing Cloud Connector enabling all the tracking info to be synchronized to Salescloud (see picture below) but, after sending some emails, I don't see where in Salescloud I can find the tracking info.

[image]

I read something about the [Email Results tab](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_si_email_results_tab_tracking_data.htm&type=5) but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this tab in Sales Cloud first: **Send Analytics**

Access the Marketing Cloud Connect Send Analytics tab within the Sales or Service Cloud. This tab provides aggregate tracking data for all sends, specific subscribers' activities, and specific email send activities. Marketing Cloud Connect reports are based on tracking data stored in the CRM.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_send_analytics.htm&type=5

Comment: thanks, do you know why I cannot see the email tracking I sent previously?

Comment: you should be able to control the time range of the graphs, unfortunately I don't have access to an account with this tab at the moment to post a screenshot

Comment: Yes, I did it, but no info is displayed

Comment: When did you enable tracking? Do you see Individual Email Results on your test contacts that you sent emails to?

Comment: The tracking was enabled when the MC connector was set-up some time ago (the test was done at the beginning of this week). I don't see the email result for the test recipient in Salescloud, but the tracking in MC shows that the email was delivered and opened.

Comment: Ok, this might mean a few things, but I would suggest opening a new thread for that for that. Just tell me how you sent the emails - to a Sales Cloud Campaign, report? To a Salesforce DE? Journey Builder with Sales Cloud data source?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99166/discussion-between-fromero-and-coderage).

Comment: Done, this is the new thread https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279674/email-tracking-is-not-synchronizing-to-salescloud